# In Python, how do I efficiently return a boolean value without incurring copy costs?

Tags: python

Say I have a class that contains a few string variables and I want to declare an `is_valid` method that checks that all the string variables are not `None`/empty

It could look like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    var1 = None
    var2 = None
    var3 = None

    @property
    def is_valid(self):
        return self.var1 and self.var2 and self.var3
```

This, from what I understand is the *pythonic* way of checking that all values are set.

Now, if `var1..3` were to hold some really long string values, `is_valid` would return the last one of these, in this case the value of `var3`. If I'm not wrong, strings in python are immutable, and therefore a copy of the string would be returned, thus making the app consume more memory.

Is it considered a better solution to implement `is_valid` as:

```
    @property
    def is_valid(self):
        return self.var1 and self.var2 and self.var3 and True
```

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I never knew Python's `and` operator worked this way. Thanks for educating me today!

Comment: @MarkRansom As answers have noted, the original pythonic way does not in fact copy anything, I suspect Klaus is thinking in C++!

Answer (score 12):

> ... a copy the string would be returned ...

Incorrect. A reference to the string object would be returned. But you can call `bool()` to convert it to a "better" value.

```
return bool(var1 and var2 and var3)
```

Comment: yours is the best way IMHO, but for the heck of it you can also `return True if var1 and var2 and var3 else False`

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, that's a construct that always makes me shudder, whatever the language. Boolean constructs are usually easier to read.

Comment: @MarkRansom True, I was just pointing out that you _can_ do that.

Answer (score 6):

Returning an object always returns a reference to that object in Python, no matter whether it is immutable or not.  And immutability would be at best a reason to make a copy unnecessary; e.g. `tuple(another_tuple)` simply returns `another_tuple`, while `list(another_list)` returns a copy of `another_list`.  For immutable objects, there is no reason to make copies.